# How to remove `Save (Ignore Alert)` and `Save & New (Ignore Alert)` buttons?

Tags: button, duplicate-management, button-overrides

I have created a duplication rule so that when a new lead record is created to notify the user if there is an already existing lead.

When there is an existing and duplicated lead I need to forbid the user from creating a new lead record.

Please advise how to be able to remove the `Save (Ignore Alert)` and `Save & New (Ignore Alert)` buttons by stopping the users to create new lead records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_what_my_users_see_classic.htm&type=5) says:

> If your duplicate rule lets reps save duplicates, they see the Save (Ignore Alert) button. If your duplicate rule blocks reps from saving duplicates, they see the Save button, but they can’t save the record.

If you don't want to allow users to ignore the error, set the Duplicate Rule to Block, not Alert.